# Splitting up an RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to split up a list of lists `((A,1,2,3),(B,4,5,6),(C,7,8,9))` into:

```
(A,1)
(A,2)
(A,3)
(B,4)
(B,5)
...
```

I tried `rdd.flatMapValues(lambda x: [x])` but it just gave me the first values.  Then I wrote a little python function:

```
item_index = []
for list in master_list:
    for item in list:
        item_index.append((list[0],item))
```

But I didn't realize you can't pass an `RDD` into it.  Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you have a `rdd` of `[["A",1,2,3],["B",4,5,6],["C",7,8,9]]`

```
master_list = sc.parallelize([["A",1,2,3],["B",4,5,6],["C",7,8,9]])
```

You can `flatMap` and do some iteration to get your desired output as

```
master_list.flatMap(lambda x: [[x[0], x[i]] for i in range(1, len(x))])
```

You must have output as

```
['A', 1]
['A', 2]
['A', 3]
['B', 4]
['B', 5]
['B', 6]
['C', 7]
['C', 8]
['C', 9]
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Hi Ramesh- That's great insight that I can iterate within the lambda.  However, when I run the code, I still get back my original lists [["A",1,2,3],["B",4,5,6],["C",7,8,9]]. I did not run the parallelize because my master_list is already an RDD. Does that sound right?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: try checking what your rdd type is . I think its not in the format i explained in the answer.

Comment: I realized that i needed to set the result to a new variable, and then the code worked.  Thanks a lot for your help. `master_2 = master_list.flatMap(lambda x: [[x[0], x[i]] for i in range(1, len(x))]`

Comment: great to hear that @L.Wise :)